# how to big api response insert in Realm DB insert in background thread and update table view ui?

Tags: realm

```
class func insertProductCombinationInDd(objects: [[String: Any]]) {
        var objs = [[String: Any]]()
        for  var object in objects {
            let attributs = object["attributes"] as? [[String: Any]]
            let strAttribute = OAxeBaseViewController.jsonString(from: attributs ?? [:])
            object["attributes"] = strAttribute
            objs.append(object)
        }
        if !objs.isEmpty {
             do {
                let realm = try Realm()
            
                try realm.write {
                    for combi in objs {
                        let combination = ProductCombination()
                        combination.id = combi["id"] as? String ?? ""
                        combination.productId = combi["product_id"] as? String ?? ""
                        combination.orgId = combi["org_id"] as? String ?? ""
                        combination.attributes = combi["attributes"] as? String ?? ""
                        combination.mrp = combi["mrp"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                        combination.quantity = combi["quantity"] as? Int ?? 0
                        combination.updatedAt = combi["updation_time"] as? Int ?? 0
                        combination.active = combi["active"] as? Bool ?? false
                        combination.categoryId = combi["category_id"] as? String ?? ""
                        realm.add(combination, update: .modified)
                    }
                }
             } catch {}
            
        }
    }
```

I written code like this
any other good approach data insert in background thread and update ui similar.
how to update ui immediately when insert or update realm objec?

Comment: Have you read the section on notifications: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications

Comment: for big data insert what can I do its take time to insert

Comment: The question is pretty vague; There's nothing in that code that does anything on a background thread. What is 'big data'? Is the code not working? If not, what's the issue? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)